# transfer a pandas dataframe with multi_index columns to R

Tags: python, r, pandas, multi-index

How can I transfer a pandas dataframe with multi index columns to R? preferably, using a CSV file?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,1,2], 'baz':['a', 'c', 'b'], 'bar':[0.2, 0.6, 0.9], 'x':[4, 0.6, 0.9]})
display(df)
df = df.groupby(['foo', 'baz']).describe()
display(df)
```

results in:
[image]

`df.to_csv("test.csv")` generates the following CSV file:

```
,,bar,bar,bar,bar,bar,bar,bar,bar,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
,,count,mean,std,min,25%,50%,75%,max,count,mean,std,min,25%,50%,75%,max
foo,baz,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,a,1.0,0.2,,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0,4.0,,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0
1,c,1.0,0.6,,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,1.0,0.6,,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6
2,b,1.0,0.9,,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,1.0,0.9,,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9
```

How can I retain this hierarchical structure? Or if not possible at least have R auto-concatenate the names to keep the information from the header

Comment: to_excel will keep the format

Comment: Georg, are you asking if R will recognize and retain the multiple rows of column headers, and/or the "index" columns? To the first, I think "no", only a single row is used as column names, all other rows are data. To the second ... `data.table` in R has the concept of keys, generally most other `data.frame`-based stuff in R does not.

Comment: Exactly, I would love for R to retain the information. If not otherwise possible, at least combine the 2 rows (concatenate them) when reading the multi-index CSV or Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Combine the multi-level name, then save to csv.

```py
# as_index=False
df = df.groupby(['foo', 'baz'], as_index=False).describe()

# combine the column level names with a .
df.columns = df.columns.map('.'.join)

 foo.count  foo.mean  foo.std  foo.min  foo.25%  foo.50%  foo.75%  foo.max  bar.count  bar.mean  bar.std  bar.min  bar.25%  bar.50%  bar.75%  bar.max  x.count  x.mean  x.std  x.min  x.25%  x.50%  x.75%  x.max
       1.0       1.0      NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0        1.0       0.2      NaN      0.2      0.2      0.2      0.2      0.2      1.0     4.0    NaN    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0    4.0
       1.0       1.0      NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0        1.0       0.6      NaN      0.6      0.6      0.6      0.6      0.6      1.0     0.6    NaN    0.6    0.6    0.6    0.6    0.6
       1.0       2.0      NaN      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0        1.0       0.9      NaN      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.9      0.9      1.0     0.9    NaN    0.9    0.9    0.9    0.9    0.9

# save to csv
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I know - this is an easy one in python. But would a similar easy step work diretly inside R?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I thought the point was to get the multi-column info into R from pandas and retain the column info.  Did I misunderstand the question?  I don't know a way to make R read all the multi-column info directly, without flattening it out.

Comment: No flattening is fine - but is it possible to flatten in R?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler That I don't know.  I'm not R proficient.  Also, I discovered it's difficult to search from information on  R, because the program name is just a letter.  Do you have a bunch of multi-index csvs from pandas that you need in R?

Comment: yes - but I think I will go the dirty quickfiy approach and and read each of them in python, cleanup and then write / rpy2 and then perform the R stuff.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler seems like a good job for `pathlib.Path().glob` and a loop.

Comment: Indeed in python this is so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to transfer a Python data frame to use in an R context directly without going through the intermediary step of a CSV: use R Markdown and create code chunks in both Python and R, using `reticulate` package to move between them. This R Markdown document renders the HTML below. Use `py$` to call Python objects in R chunks after they are created.

````
---
title: "Pandas Exchange"
date: "5/8/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
```

## Using a Pandas Data Frame in R

First load your Pandas data frame into variable `df`:

```{python}
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,1,2], 'baz':['a', 'c', 'b'], 'bar':[0.2, 0.6, 0.9], 'x':[4, 0.6, 0.9]})
df = df.groupby(['foo', 'baz']).describe()
print(df)
```
Then use it from within an R chunk:

```{r}
py$df %>% kable()
```
````

When you render this in R Studio, you get:

[image]

Comment: Well obviously yes - and this is the other way round (reticulate vs rpy2) what I expected. Still nice. But regarding the MultiIndex columns - it looks like kable is not flattening them and introduces duplicate columns.